# How can show the Desktop(Springboard) on my app?

Tags: iphone, desktop, transparent

I want to make app that shows Springboard like SBSetting on Cydia.
It is transparent.
I tried 
'[viewctrl view].backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];', but it is not work.
Who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible on the official way.